# Anecdote about a seemingly possible, but actually impossible task given to students

Tags: anecdote

There is a story I often tell my students about tasks that seem possible but are actually impossible, but I can hardly remember the details, and I am hoping that someone here would remember. Here is what I remember: A professor back in the 70s hired two undergraduate students to complete a task that he thought must be easy but was actually impossible at that time.

I vaguely remember that the professor wanted a computer program that would understand human language and the two students were computer science students. However, these details might be completely wrong.

If anyone knows this story and where I can get more details about it, it would be great.

Comment: The 70's were a great time for optimism in AI. I don't know the story, but Joel Moses might be involved. Noam Chomsky?

Comment: The Dartmouth Workshop on AI might be a good example, initially they thought they could solve important problems of AI within six weeks: https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-birthplace-of-ai-9ab7d4e5fb00
More generally, for AI optimism, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_artificial_intelligence#Optimism

Comment: @Buffy I find it pretty unlikely 70s Chomsky thought two undergrads could just whip up a program to understand human language.

Comment: And then there is the opposite: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/the-unsolvable-math-problem/

Comment: Well, https://xkcd.com/1425/ captures some of the issues.

Comment: Sure. Once there was this prof who wanted me to look up a story from a fragment of a description. It seemed like an easy thing but...

Comment: Jon Custer gives the answer, here https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1425:_Tasks you can find the whole story

Comment: Thank you Jon Custer and user6530. xkcd is probably where I originally got the story from.

Comment: I am still optimistic: very few problems are actually impossible, and "impossible" problems are still worth working on. But there is hardly a shortage of hard problems which people hope to be solvable in a short time. Why, just recently I got contacted by a team hoping I would help them with AI stuff *after* they won a grant featuring AI front and center, and in the "hard" formulation it probably would not be solved for some 10+ years, while with an obvious simplification it does not need AI in the first place.